# Question about 50ohm impedance matching circuit

Tags: antenna, impedance, matching

I am implementing rf energy harvesting circuit. The rectenna is working at 915MHz and the impedance is 50Ω. I think L-matching may be the easiest. However, I don't have the vector network analyzer. Is there any way to calculate the parameters without the analyzer? Thanks. Here is the structure.[image]

Comment: What is the load? draw out your entire schematic.

Comment: I had uploaded a simplified structure diagram. I don't know the value of the load. I thought that we just consider the load of the rectifying circuit? Or should including the sensor load?

Comment: your capacitor should be in parallel, not in series as you have a DC Block here.

Comment: @SirSy, this is an abstract block diagram, not a circuit diagram.